# Preserve \r\n on XElement.Load

Tags: c#

Is there a way i can preserve\r\n on XElement.Load().

```
  TextReader reader = new StringReader(rawInputString);//rawInputString is just text in html format
    XElement root = XElement.Load(reader);
```

**Edit :**

```
string  rawInputString =  "<Html><Body><p></p> \r\n <p></p>\r\n \r\n \r\n </Body></Html>";
```

After XELement.Load the output i want is the same when i do root.ToString() :

```
"<Html><Body><p></p> \r\n <p></p>\r\n \r\n \r\n </Body></Html>"
```

For Now it just cleans/removes up the \r\n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
XElement root = XmlElement.Load(reader, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

Check this article for more information: [Preserving White Space while Loading or Parsing XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387014.aspx)

In addition, callling the `XElement.ToString()` method will cause the `XElement` to apply its own formatting. In order to prevent that, you must call `XElement.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)`

Comment: @Sven i think it will preserve only white sapce rt?

Comment: Line breaks are a form of whitespace, so it will preserve them as well.

Comment: Could you post an example of your XML, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens? I just tested it myself and it definitely does preserve newlines in non-significant whitepace.

Comment: I tested your sample, and PreserveWhitespace works for me. Note however that `ToString()` causes the XML to be reformatted, and if you want to prevent that, you must use `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting` (I've udated my answer accordingly)