# How to load an XDocument preserving `\r\n`

Tags: .net, xml

A `var doc = XDocument.Parse("<r>a\r\nb</r>")` and then `doc.Root.Value` gives me `a\n\b` instead of the expected `a\r\nb`. I tried most of the `Parse` and `Load` overloads, using `XmlReader`, `Stream`, `TextReader`, but didn't manage to load the `\r\n` as `\r\n`; I always get a `\n`. I'm using .NET 6 on Windows.

There is this [question about XElement.Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413035/preserve-r-n-on-xelement-load) with an answer suggesting to use `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace`, but this doesn't work for me when using `XDocument.Load` or `XDocument.Parse`.

How can I load an XML document containing a `\r\n` in a value into an `XDocument` preserving that `\r\n`?

Comment: It's simply not compliant to have XML with `\r` in it, you need to encode it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/S5ZC0B

Comment: @Charlieface You are right, thanks! The [End-of-Line Handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends) section in the XML spec is the key point. If you post this as answer, I'll mark it as accepted. By the way, as I understand it, it's compliant to have `\r` in XML, but a compliant parser ignores it.

Comment: You should have a button to accept the above link as a duplicate